# Angular 2 unit testing - multiple class instance

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I am trying to set up unit test for simple Angular 2 app. I walk into trouble, beacuse unit tests creates multiple instances of class. See the code below

app.component.ts

```
import { TestClass } from './test.class';
import { Service } from './service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private s: Service) {
        let c = new TestClass();
    }
}
```

test.class.ts

```
export class TestClass {
    static counts = 0;

    constructor() {
        TestClass.counts++;
        if (TestClass.counts > 1)
            throw "Multiple TestClass instance";
    }
}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { Service } from './service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
describe('AppComponent', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent],
            providers: [Service]
        }).createComponent(AppComponent);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        fixture.destroy();
    });

    it('1', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    it('2', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The result of tests

```
[1]     Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template
:0:0 caused by: Multiple TestClass instance
```

Is there a way to delete class instance before run next "it"?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve with `AppComponent.counts`?

Comment: I want to prevent to create second AppComponent instance

Comment: Well I can see that, but *why*? The whole point of DI is that you don't have to manage those lifecycles yourself.

Comment: The point is that I want to have singleton

Comment: Guess what I'm going to ask... Why?

Comment: yes, why?  Why is a component a singleton?

Comment: I want my TestClass to be singleton.  I have multiple services which fill fields of this class as needed. To avoid mess, I want to have one class instance in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple instances of `TestClass` are being created because `AppComponent` is being created by `TestBed` once for every `it` block. In the above case that would be twice. `afterEach` runs once after every `it` block, There you can reset the static variable `counts`

```
describe('AppComponent', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent],
            providers: [Service]
        }).createComponent(AppComponent);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        fixture.destroy();
        TestClass.counts = 0
    });
......
```

This way you don't have to delete the `TestClass` it self to reset the `counts` variable

EDIT : Alternative method :

Since you are already destroying the component in the `afterEach` block, you can use `ngOnDestroy` life cycle hook on `AppComponent` to reset the count variable there it self. The logic here being that if the component itself is destroyed, Then so is the instance of `TestClass`. It has to be done this way as typescript does not have the concept of *destructors*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy{
    constructor(private s: Service) {
        let c = new TestClass();
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
       TestClass.counts = 0;
    }
}
```